# Event keyup doesn't work in Mozilla - knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and have this binding

```
data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'input', event: { keyup: submitOnKeyPress }"
```

and submitOnKeyPress function is in view model and look like this:

```
self.submitOnKeyPress = function() {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        self.login();
      }
    };
```

This works in every browser except Mozilla. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for solution using knockout. :-/

Comment: The solution (or at least part of it) is to stop using deprecated features.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm required to use them. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
self.submitOnKeyPress = function(data, event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        self.login();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I could never suppose this can resolve the problem.